# Linux permissions - user vs group permission

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions

I know that the permissions listing are for user , then the group and the third one is for other users.

**my example :**

```
_rwxr--r-- tooth face file1.txt
_rwxr--r-- eye face file2.txt
_rwxr--r-- leg face file3.txt
```

**groups included**

```
tooth : face head 
eye : face head 
leg : body
```

**Now, my question is :**
whether "leg" will have rwx permissions to file3 as it is not a member in group "face" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file permissions are:

```
_rwxr--r-- leg face file3.txt
 ^^^   ^^^
  |  ^^^ |
  |   |   others
  |   group
  owner
```

This means that:

- user `leg` has `rwx` permissions.
- other users from group `face` have `r--` permissions.
- the rest of the users who are not in the group `face` have `r--` permissions.

Since the owner is `leg`, this user will of course have `rwx` permissions.